# Discord Python Slash Commands do not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot with python. Unfortunatly my slash command wouldn't show up even after a few restarts and invites. I used the same code for another bot and just one of these slash commands worked. I changed the name in dev portal but it doesn't change at the server so I set up a completely new application. But now nothing works except that I can start the bot and it is running on the server but without commands available. Here is my Code:

```
import discord

from discord import app_commands
from discord import Embed
from discord import Interaction

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = discord.Client(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('is playing'), status=discord.Status.online)

@tree.command(name='test', description='this is just a simple reply test')
async def test(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'test has worked, {interaction.user.mention}')

@tree.command(name='clear', description='Clears the channels last messages')
async def clear(interaction: Interaction, amount: int):
    if amount > 0:
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    else:
        await interaction.channel.send('Give me a valid number, starting from "0"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run('MySecret')
```

I already tried to delete the app from the discord server and invite again. I also tried to restart the app but nothing changed anyway.

I have the correct secret because the bot starts there are just no commands available. In addition, the bot does not have the slash emoji in its profile.

Comment: Your prefix is `!`, not slash.  Right?

Comment: yes thats the prefix for regular commands. But I thought that regular commands and slash commands both can be used in parallel.

I want to run the clear and test command as tree commands.

Comment: But those commands are sub-commands of your bot that uses `'!'`, right?  Now, I'll admit my knowledge of discord bots comes from answering question here, so I could be mistaken, but that's what I would assume.

Comment: See [my bot’s commands are not showing up!](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-bot-s-commands-are-not-showing-up) FAQ.

Comment: I believe you can use a command both with the prefix and a slash by using ```hybrid_command``` instead of regular ```command```, which  (I think) only works with normal prefixes. See [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#hybrid-commands) part of the discord.py docs for more info, it also has some other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got an answer. I forgot to sync the commands. Its basically one simple line which I added in the on_ready method:

```py
await tree.sync(guild=None)
```

Comment: Yes. The commands need to be synced with the server :D